# Duplicate tag [blueprint][blueprint-css]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blueprint

> Blueprint is a CSS framework that comes with an easy-to-use grid, sensible typography, useful plugins, and a stylesheet for printing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blueprint-css

> Blueprint is a CSS framework, which aims to cut down on your development time. It gives you a solid foundation to build your project on top of, with an easy-to-use grid, sensible typography, useful plugins, and even a stylesheet for printing.

Is there something to be done about this?

Comment: Mark them as synonyms.

Comment: I don't have the reputation

Comment: Well then, somebody do it.

Comment: @easterlyirk cinnamons

Comment: Yes @easterlyirk ?

Comment: It is a homonym with synonyms @easterlyirk

Comment: @Neal not really. Sinnamin != Sinna*nim*.